# successful file upload opens new blank page, also allows "empty/blank" to upload

Tags: html, ajax, file-upload

following code is working but with 2 issues: It is part of bigger form on the web page it appears on.

```
<FORM id="my_file_upld_form"
 style="display: inline;"
 METHOD="POST"
 ACTION="/cgi-bin/fileupload_ajax.pl"
    ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data">
    <INPUT TYPE="file" class="ajaxfileupload" NAME="myfile" SIZE="42">
    <input type="hidden" class="ajaxfileupload" name="fileupload" value="ajax_fileupload">
    <input class="ajaxfileupload" type="submit" value="Upload"/>
</FORM>
```

1. it is allowing "blank" or empty (no file selection and upload button clicked) to upload. which is causing 500 error on server.
2. bigger problem is: after the file is uploaded, a new blank page is opened in browser and user has to use back button to go back to the page from where this was run. This happens irrespective of the fact that the ajax script returns anything back or not.

how to fix? I am open to replace this piece of code on the page, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell exactly what is going wrong without your java script code. However I think I know how to fix some of your problems.

1. Don't trust the client you need to handle in your backend code the ability to handle a form that gives you bad data. You can validate the form client side but you always need to validate server side as well.
2. I suspect this problem is happening because you aren't preventing the default event in javascript. In jquery you would do

   ```
   $("#my_file_upld_form").submit(function(e){
              e.preventDefault()
   })
   ```